# Need suggestions for displaying somewhat complex table with ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I don't have much experience with ASP.NET Web Forms and need to generate somewhat complex table.

I have following classes:

```
public class ServiceTable
{
    ...
    public IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public IList<ServiceJob> ServiceJobs { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Service
{
    ...
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public IList<ServiceJob> ServiceJobs { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ServiceJob
{
    ...
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I need to display a column for each `Service` in `ServiceTable`, header should be `ServiceName`. Then I need a row for each `ServiceJob` that `ServiceTable`  has and first column in each row should be `JobName` and next ones should be checkboxes which are checked if corresponding service has that `ServiceJob`.
Little mockup:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+  
|         | ServiceName1 | ServiceName2 | ServiceName..n|  
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+  
| JobName | ckbx         | ckbx         | ckbx          |  
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I'm thinking about gridview, but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish that.

I need to use this table to diplay already entered data and to enter new data.

Looking formward for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use nested gridviews to achive that ... here is the [walkthough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)